# How to Remove windows from UIApplication in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwindow, uiapplication

While clicking on the button , i am moving to another view controller using the following code.

```
var window: UIWindow?
window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.autoresizesSubviews = true
window?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
let trackingViewController = LoginCameraViewController.init(screen: 
.main)
window?.rootViewController = trackingViewController
window?.addSubview((trackingViewController?.view)!)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.layoutSubviews()
```

For every button click, a new window is added to the application.I want to remove the latest window added.
The number of windows present in the application can be known by using following code.

```
let windowz = UIApplication.shared.windows
print("subviews",windowz)
```

Comment: Why do you keep adding a new window instead of using the one you have?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the below code windowz is normal array.

```
let windowz = UIApplication.shared.windows
```

You can remove last by using

```
windowz.removeLast()
```

Comment: @CyberMew were you able to resolve issue for iOS 13?

Comment: @Niki unfortunately no, and with multi-windows coming up I’m not sure if I want to continue to manipulate them manually..

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the wrong concept of navigation in iOS. Window is like a root object in which ViewControllers appear. So probably the solution you're looking in a first place is `UINavigationController`.

[Apple Documentation on Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

> For iOS 13 i was able to do it this way

I created array which contains the window using which this new viewController is being presented,

```
var arrWindow = [UIWindow]()
arrWindow.append(yourNewWindow)
```

> // Note: This will be stored as strong reference so need to remove it.

Also store your original window in variable

```
let originalWindow = yourOriginalWindow
```

> // Note: Same goes for this as well ,this will be stored as strong reference so need to remove it.

At the time of removing there are many ways to do it but this was the most suited way for me,

```
 func removeAppendedWindow() {

     for window in arrWindow {
         if window != originalWindow {
              if let index = arrWindow.index(of: window) {
                  window.isHidden = true
                  arrWindow.remove(at: index)
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @CyberMew I was able to handle at least my situation the way i mentioned it above. :)

Answer (score -3):

You should use View Controller instead of adding windows and pop it instead where you are removing the window.
Window is only one object for app and will contain the views.
Please correct your understanding and use View controllers.

Comment: UIWindow is UIView at its core. There is nothing wrong with using UIWindow in your app where it makes sense.

Comment: Actually an App can have multiple windows